# How to exclude values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a simple excel problem:

I have columns A, B, C, D how can I get all the values that are in column A that are not in column B +C +D together in excel?

Comment: Are you looking for Excel-only solutions or would VBA work too?

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated column E that is set to 1 if `A <> B and A <> C and A <> D`, else is set to 0.

Using the Auto-Filter function on the Data Ribbon select only those rows that have a value of 1 in column E.